# KeyboardAvoidingView not scrolling to focused element using this structure in react native?

Tags: react-native

I'm using the following structure, and for some reason, whenever focusing a TextInput, is not scrolling to it.

```
<SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
   <KeyboardAvoidingView
          style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'column', justifyContent: 'center'}} 
          behavior="padding" 
          enabled 
          keyboardVerticalOffset={90}
    >
      <ScrollView>
      </ScrollView>
   </KeyboardAvoidingView>
</SafeAreaView>
```

Why could this be? Also, if possible, can I scroll to any element on touch even if it's not a TextInput? Let's say I got a Picker, a Toggle button, etc. Is it possible to scroll to that element?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you share your exact code? I am not facing this kind of issue.

Comment: @VishalRabadiya seems that the problem in my case was the behavior="padding"... whenever i used position it worked as expect. Why is that?

Comment: behavior="padding" works on iOS and for android you have to disabled instead of enabled in KeyboardAvoidingView